# How to write a CQL script that modifies data conditionally?

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I need to write a set of CQL scripts where whether the meat of the script runs or not should depend on the presence of some data.  Is there a way to write something of this sort:

```
if(insert into table ... values ... if not exists) {
 // the real script
} else {
 // print some error description
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't be able to do that directly in a CQL script, since there is no if statement control logic in CQL.

But you could do that in a bash script that invokes cqlsh.

You can run commands in bash like this:

```
cqlsh -e "insert into test.t1 (p,c) values (1,8) IF NOT EXISTS;"

 [applied]
-----------
      True
```

That means the row did not exist and it was inserted.  Now if you try to insert it again, it will fail like this:

```
cqlsh -e "insert into test.t1 (p,c) values (1,8) IF NOT EXISTS;"

 [applied] | p | c | v
-----------+---+---+------
     False | 1 | 8 | null
```

So what you can do is capture that output, and then check if it was applied or not, with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=`cqlsh -e "insert into test.t1 (p,c) values (1,8) IF NOT EXISTS;"`

if [[ $result == *"applied"*"True"* ]]
then
    echo "the real script"
else
    echo "some error"
fi
```

The other way to do this would be to write a Cassandra client using the java driver.  It can do the "INSERT...IF NOT EXISTS" or "UPDATE...IF" and then test if the statement was applied and respond accordingly.